# Any idea about how to use monkeyrunner drag more than one at same time?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

For now, use drag function of monkeyrunner to swipe, it is working fine. But is it possible, perform two drag lines at same time? I just attempt to use idea with thread, but no luck for me, only one drag line at specific time.

Comment: Why do you want to drag more than one at the same time? What are you expecting to happen when you do?

Comment: just one thought comes into my head when I played fruit ninja game, whether or not can do more than one dragging line at the same time!

Comment: Well there are some apps that let you do pinching which would technically be two drags at the same time.